# html reference to jquery library + external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reference

I am wondering how to reference `jquery` in `html`.

To my understanding there has to be 2 links:

1. To the library
2. To the external file.

here is my reference that does not seem to work..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

ps. 1st time here, I know the question sounds stupid, I'm just going crazy with that

Comment: what language are you coming from?

Comment: His English wasn't that bad xD

Comment: im originally from Yakutsk, Russia; my English is a combination of local studies + Finnish English + German English :>

Comment: Your English is totally fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need one reference. Let's say your folder structure is like this:

```
my_project/
    index.html
    jquery.js
```

Then in your index.html you just need to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
```

To include the JS file.  If however you don't have jquery.js there, and you want to reference it from a CDN (content delivery network). You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: They both load the jquery library. The second loads it from Google, and the first loads it if you have that directory structure listed above and jquery downloaded locally. It will probably be easier to do the second though, so you don't have to worry about downloading the file

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use a CDN, or content delivery network, as the host for jQuery and other similar libraries. [This article](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) does a good job of explaining the benefits. One example of a quality, free CDN is [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery). Here's how you would include Google's version of jQuery 2.1.3:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

link from file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

link from source

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thesource.com/jquery.js"></script>`

internal script

`<script>
 // javascript here
</script>`

Comment: if you want it external, just put your script into a file and then give it an extension .js and then link or include it on your page.

Answer (score 0):

1 to the library:     `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2 to the external js file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pinkmoon.js"></script>`, assuming that js file is in the same folder as index.html